# Change the colors at the bottom of beamer package for the theme Madrid

Tags: beamer, color

For my work at school, I sometimes create notes with the `beamer` library. Changing style changes the colors. I chose the style `Madrid` with the option `\usecolortheme{crane}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%%% Dichiarazione dei pacchetti standard.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,braket}
\usepackage{colortbl, multicol}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
%\usepackage{showkeys}


%%% Personalizzazione del layout---articolata su cinque livelli.
\usetheme{Madrid}        % layout complessivo. 
\useinnertheme{default} % layout interno.
\useoutertheme{default} % layout esterno.
\usecolortheme{crane} % schema di colori.
\usefonttheme{default}  % schema dei font.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{\textbf{Matematica}}
\subtitle{Successioni a termini reali -- prima parte}
\author{Star Trek}
\institute{}
\date{\today}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=5pt,text margin right=4.8pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section[Sommario]{Successioni}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Diseguaglianze e teorema preliminare}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Valore assoluto, diseguaglianze e teorema preliminare}
\index{Diseguaglianze e teorema preliminare} 
Se $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $\abs{x}=\ldots$, $\abs{x}\geq 0.$. Si hanno anche le seguenti proprietà $\abs{x}=\max\Set{-x, x}$. $|-x| = |x| , x \leq |x|, |xy| = |x| |y|$.
\[\abs{x+y}\leq \abs{x}+\abs{y}, \quad \textup{(disuguaglianza triangolare)}\]
\[\abs{\abs{x}-\abs{y}}\leq \abs{x-y}\leq \abs{x}+\abs{y}\]
\begin{theorem}
Se $x\in \mathbb{R}$ e $\forall\epsilon>0$, $|x|<\epsilon$ allora  $x=0$.
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there the possibility to differentiate the color of the three gradations?

Comment: @down-voter: Is there a serious reason or motivation for this downvote to my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the Madrid `beamer` theme. If I look in this file, I find this line:

```
\useoutertheme{infolines}
```

And if I look in that file, I find these lines:

```
\setbeamercolor*{author in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary}
\setbeamercolor*{title in head/foot}{parent=palette secondary}
\setbeamercolor*{date in head/foot}{parent=palette primary}
```

This gives the names of the colours in the three panels. By default they are set to the primary, secondary, and tertiary palettes.

So we could change these palettes:

```
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{fg=black,bg=magenta!50}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{fg=black,bg=yellow!50}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=cyan!50}
```

But this might change other things too, so instead you might want to change the colours directly:

```
\setbeamercolor*{author in head/foot}{fg=black,bg=magenta!50}
\setbeamercolor*{title in head/foot}{fg=black,bg=yellow!50}
\setbeamercolor*{date in head/foot}{fg=black,bg=cyan!50}
```

Output is the same in both cases:

[image: example colour output]

Comment: To write thank you very much to you is very little for my opinion. As Eros Ramazzotti sang in one of his songs, thank you to exist. This rule also to you :)